# Remove WPSystem folder from SD card

Tags: windows-10-mobile, micro-sd

I have reset my phone (Microsoft Lumia 535) due to some reasons.
I saw that there is a huge Folder named WPsystem in my SD card. So I think these are apps and other data which installed by me.
So now I think I do not need them because now system is clean and I have to install the apps again.

But I can not remove the WPSystem folder.
I tried with a card reader.
First it deletes perfectly. But when I put the reader back it haven't delete. I also tried to format the SD card. But it says "Windows can not format"

So how can I fix this, I want to remove the WPsystem folder.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1**

Format it via phone. Windows phone will format the SD card and remove the old app data.

**Solution 2**

Connect your SD Card to a Linux PC. I have tried deleting System folders from Linux. It works perfectly.

Comment: I tried to format via phone. But it did not work.

Comment: @user3199385 what about formatting / deleting files via Linux

Comment: No its not formatting and all files are again restored in sd card..pls help me..

Answer (score -1):

If you store the apps/music/downloaded itens/pictures on SD Card, you cannot remove WPSystem. This directory is used by Windows Mobile/Widows Phone to store configurations, data from apps and another internal stuff.

Comment: Since you can remove the SD card you can also format it or delete the WPSystem folder.